# Dojo Toolkit and gRafael conflict

Tags: javascript, dojo

When I try to use both libraries in one script - the parts using Dojo are ok, but the ones using gRafael not working. I see the "Raphael is not defined" error message in FireBug console.

How can I make these tools work together?

UPDATE: I was incorrect. The Dojo parts are not working too.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see how you load both libraries. Also let us know which versions of each one you are using.

Comment: i develop an application in which every library is loaded inside so-called "widgets" with head.js. the version are the latest ones.

i found an article where someone complains the same conflict. it is avoid if i call gRafael before Dojo. but it's not suitable - sometimes i will need to call Dojo before rRafael.

Comment: If dojo and rRafael are the "only" 2 libraries involved, why don't you get rid of head.js and load raphael using the dojo amd loader instead ? Can you post the code of your page so that I see how you try to load dojo and raphael ?